# How to insert data and get id as out parameter in android room and rxjava 2?

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

Insert query

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
long insertProduct(Product product);   //product id is auto generated
```

view model

```
public Completable insertProduct(final String productName) {
    return new CompletableFromAction(() -> {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setProductName(productName);
        mProductDataSource.insertOrUpdateProduct(newProduct);
    });
}
```

In activity where I called this above function I used CompositeDisposable.

```
CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

 mDisposable.add(mViewModel.insertProduct(productName))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(() ->{} ,throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Error msg", throwable)));
```

Am I implementing in wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#daos-convenience). If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.
Since you insert only one item, the method will return only one rowID.

So, try this

```
Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
           return productDao.insertProduct(new Product()));
        }
    })
    .subscribe(id -> {

    } ,throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Error msg", throwable)))
```

You could use `Observable` or `Maybe` as well. But  I think `Single` fits better since in your case the id is autogenerated and the insertion should always complete.

Comment: Here I using android view model where I facing difficulty on how to write viewmodel function. I have given the code where I use Completable to insert product.

Comment: As your suggestion I use Single
 `public Single<Product> insertProduct(final String productName) {
      return new Single<Product>() {
          @Override
          protected void subscribeActual(SingleObserver<? super Product> observer) {
              Product newProduct = new Product();
              newProduct.setProductName(productName);
             productDataSource.insertOrUpdateProduct(newProduct);
          }
      };
   }`  but thats not work, may be I miss something.

Comment: I think you need to check the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables) on how to create an `Observable`.