# Executing delete in main thread room using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am using Room is for storing information about cart details.

I want to `detele` the records in the main thread. I am getting error

> can not access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the up for a long period of time

I checked the below links but dint help me

[executing delete with room (rxjava)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921312/executing-delete-with-room-rxjava)

[How to insert data and get id as out parameter in android room and rxjava 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754378/how-to-insert-data-and-get-id-as-out-parameter-in-android-room-and-rxjava-2)

DaoAccess.java

```
    @Dao
    public interface DaoAccess {

        @Insert
        void insertMultipleRecord(DBProducts... universities);

        @Insert
        void insertMultipleListRecord(List<DBProducts> universities);

        @Insert
        void insertOnlySingleRecord(DBProducts university);


        @Query("SELECT * FROM DBProducts")
        LiveData<List<DBProducts>> fetchAllData();


        @Update
        void updateRecord(DBProducts university);

        @Delete
        void deleteRecord(DBProducts university);
    }
```

Application.class

```
    public class PRApp extends Application {
        private static PRApp m_instance;
        DBHelper dbHelper;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mInstance = this;
            prefs = new PRPrefs(this);
            m_instance = this;

            sDefSystemLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
            switch (sDefSystemLanguage) {
                case "en":
                    sDefSystemLanguageCode = "1";
                    break;
                case "ar":
                    sDefSystemLanguageCode = "2";
                    break;
                default:
                    sDefSystemLanguageCode = "3";
                    break;
            }
        }


        public DBHelper getRoomDB() {
            dbHelper = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                    DBHelper.class, "prasukh-db").build();
            return dbHelper;

        }



    }
```

My Async Task its working

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        PRApp.getInstance().getRoomDB().daoAccess().deleteRecord(products.get(position));
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Integer agentsCount) {
                        Utilities.decrementBadegeCount();
                        productsArrayList.remove(position);
                        cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        setCartLayout();
                    }
                }.execute();
```

How to achieve this in RxJava.Because my `DAO delete` returning `void`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromCallable` operator.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    PRApp.getInstance().getRoomDB().daoAccess().deleteRecord(products.get(position));
    return true;
}).firstOrError()
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<String>>() {

          @Override
          public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(List<String> strings) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable e) {

          }

      });
      // or only
      .subscribe()
      // But if an error occurred  in delete operation the app will crash
```

this execute the delete operation and produce a `Observable<Boolean>`.

Or you can allow access to database in main thread using

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),DBHelper.class, "prasukh-db")
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build();
```

but this is discouraged because of the performance.

Comment: I tried Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    PRApp.getInstance().getRoomDB().daoAccess().deleteRecord(products.get(position));
    return true;
})  not working?

Comment: @R2R Are your subscribing to it? fromCallable only execute if you subscribe to it.

Comment: Im new to rxjava so can you share how to subcribe that

Comment: @R2R I edited the answer. If you have a question ask. Happy to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163090/discussion-between-r2r-and-udeshuk).